How to Select the 1st option from dropdown in testcafe
I am trying to select the first option from a dropdown in my private webpage.
What I am trying to do is to click on the dropdown and select the very first option available without knowing its value. When I use the nth() function it throws the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nth')

this.dropdownname = Selector('#e220usr');
await t.click(dropdownname ).nth(1);

For other drop down fields where I know what value I have to select, I am using the below code and this works:
this.dropdownname = Selector('#e220usr'); 
this.dropdownnameOpt = this.dropdownname.find('option'); 
await t 
  .click(dropdownname) 
  .click(dropdownnameOpt).withText("Melissa");

